# Propertychanged is null when RaisePropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, relaycommand, propertychanged

I'm making the game carcassonne and I'm using MVVM. So I have one window (ApplicationView) and several UserControls (for each view). The window contains al the viewModels and the views in Datacontext. In this window I use a ContentControl to display the right view on the right time (content databound to a prop in viewModel of window), this change in view is done in each viewModel. So for example from loginview to menuview I use one button with command Datacontext.changePage (located in ApplicationViewModel) and I bind the next viewmodel to the commandparameter.

This works great for all the different views but for the login view I first need to check the username and password, so instead of Datacontext.changePage I wrote a new command that doesn't require any params, it only runs a method that controls the password and username (both databound to a prop in same viewmodel). This all works fine, so after I ran the changePage command (via singleton design pattern), it changes the CurrentPageViewModel to the correct one.

The problem is it doesn't update my GUI (so it doesn't change the viewModel to the correct one), when I debug it the propertychanged of the databounded prop in the MainWindowViewModel is null. So this means it doesn't recognizes any changes in the property, but i did change the prop so I just don't know what the problem is here!

ApplicationView xaml:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModel}">
        <vw:LoginView />
    </DataTemplate>        
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MenuViewModel}">
        <vw:MenuView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:NewGameViewModel}">
        <vw:NewGameView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BoardViewModel}">
        <vw:BoardView />
    </DataTemplate>      
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Cursor="/Images/Arrow.cur">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
</Grid>
```

ApplicationViewModel

```
    public ICommand ChangePageCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_changePageCommand == null)
            {
                _changePageCommand = new RelayCommand<IPageViewModel>(p =>ChangeViewModel(p),p => p is IPageViewModel);
            }

            return _changePageCommand;
        }
    }

    public void ChangeViewModel(IPageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Changing viewmodel");
        CurrentPageViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public IPageViewModel CurrentPageViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentPageViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_currentPageViewModel != value)
            {
                _currentPageViewModel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentPageViewModel");
            }
        }
    }
```

Command in LoginViewModel that changes CurrentPageViewModel via Singlton design patttern:

```
    private MenuViewModel _mvm = new MenuViewModel(null);
    public MenuViewModel mvm
    {
        get { return _mvm;}
        set {
            if (value != _mvm)
            {
                _mvm = value;
            }
        }
    }
    private RelayCommand _loginCommand;
    public ICommand LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_loginCommand == null)
            {
                _loginCommand = new RelayCommand(CheckLogin);
            }
            return _loginCommand;
        }
    }        

    private bool _ready;
    public bool ready
    {
        get 
        {
            _ready = false;
            if (_pswd != null && _pswd != "" && _usrn != null && _usrn != "")
            {
               _loggedPlayer = checkLoginDb();
               if (_loggedPlayer != null)
                   return true;
            }
            return _ready;       
        }
    }

    private void CheckLogin()
    {
        if (ready) {
            mvm = new MenuViewModel(_loggedPlayer);
            RaisePropertyChanged("mvm");  
            ApplicationViewModel.Instance.ChangeViewModel((IPageViewModel)mvm);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you using an MVVM Library like MVVM Light or Caliburn Micro? If not can you provide us with your `RaisePropertyChanged` implementation?

Comment: I am using MVVM Light, and the handler = this.propertyChanged  is always null

Comment: so if you put a break point inside the if(ready) , do you ever reach it and mvm property gets assigned?

Comment: Yes, and it changes the CurrentPageViewModel in the ApplicationViewModel, when I run the RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentPageViewModel"); the PropertyChanged is null

Comment: Is the ApplicationViewModel.Instance the DataContext of the MainWindow?

Comment: Yes, the window i'm using is ApplicationView and I did set the Datacontext of the Window to ApplicationViewModel.Instance

Comment: ok, so is the ChangeViewModel method on the ApplicationViewModel the same as on the MainWindowViewModel? From the code above I see that whenever you call the ChangePageCommand then it changes the page on MainWindowViewModel. However, when you call CheckLogin, the page is changed on ApplicationViewModel.

Comment: There is only one window: ApplicationView, and the changepagecommand is located in the ApplicationViewModel. My bad i miss wrote it in the code above.

Comment: Binding works fine, but it just looks like it doesn't catch any changes in CurrentPageViewModel